# Matlab newff, trainbr get number of ephocs run before maximum MU has been reached

Tags: matlab, neural-network, feed-forward

When training a nn using trainbr like this:

```
net = newff( inputs_train, outputs_train, layers, { 'tansig', 'purelin' }, 'trainbr' );
net.trainParam.goal = 0.0;
net.trainParam.show = 1;
net.trainParam.epochs = ephocs;
net = train( net, inputs_train, outputs_train );
```

How do I obtain the number of epohcs/iterations that has been run before max mu has been reached?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the newer FEEDFORWARDNET instead of the old NEWFF.

You can get the training record as a second argument from TRAIN:

```
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs_train,outputs_train);
tr.num_epochs
```

Comment: Cheers, I wasn't aware that it was a new function, ill give it a go, when I get home.